# CSS flex box - how to make items center vertically with a full height background

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to align some text within a box vertically centered, whilst ensuring the background colour stretches full height.

HTML:

```
<div class="feature-content">
<div class="feature-visual">
    <div class="embed-container">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/214852366?controls=0&amp;hd=1&amp;autohide=1" title="Factory Pattern &amp; REHAU" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" width="640" height="312" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="quote">
    <div class="words">Improved our conversion rates to a level that far surpassed expectation.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
article section.case-study .feature-content {
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    display: flex;
    padding-top: .35em;
}
article section.case-study .feature-content .feature-visual {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 65%;
}
article section.case-study .feature-content .quote {
    align-self: stretch;
    background: #db6f72;
    color: #FFF;
    flex-basis: 35%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;
}
article section.case-study .feature-content .quote .words {
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding-top: 4.5em;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Current live version here https://factorypattern.co.uk/case-study/rehau-interactive-touchscreen/

Image here of what I want it to look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUCy0.png)

Any assistance greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You could atleast markup or comment if my or any of the solutions helped your query.

Comment: @Highdef yes, your answer helped fix this problem. Really appreciate the help. Tried to upvote your answer, but Stackoverflow doesn't let me unless I've reached a certain reputation. I'll comment directly on your reply to let others know it worked! :)

Comment: you might be able to mark the answer though I think but anyways your welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the following changes in order to align the items to the center of your .quote container:

- First, remove the padding-top:4.5em from your .words CSS otherwise the Y-offset will be shifted down.
- Second, change the display of .quote to flex and then use align-items property to vertically align the .word container in the middle of your .quote container. `(display:flex;  align-items:center;) in .quote`

```css
.feature-content {
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: .35em;
}

.feature-visual {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 65%;
}

.quote {
  align-self: stretch;
  background: #db6f72;
  color: #FFF;
  flex-basis: 35%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.words {
  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
  padding-left:2em;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature-content">
  <div class="feature-visual">
    <div class="embed-container">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/214852366?controls=0&amp;hd=1&amp;autohide=1" title="Factory Pattern &amp; REHAU" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" width="640" height="312" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="quote">
    <div class="words">Improved our conversion rates to a level that far surpassed expectation.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Highdef this worked perfectly. I'm feeling sooooo aligned right now. :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS rule for the right block (the one containing the text quote) where you can add this in order to center its content vertically (it makes that item itself a flex container):

```
article section.case-study .feature-content .quote {
    [ ... original settings remin unchanged ... ]
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

In addition you have to erase the `padding-top` from this rule to avoid a vertical offset from the center:

```
article section.case-study .feature-content .quote .words {
    font-family: "Georgia",serif;
    font-size: 1.85em;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.3;
    /* padding-top: 1.25em; */ --> erase / set to zero
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by changing your css to:

```
article section.case-study .feature-content {
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    display: flex;
    padding-top: .35em;
}
article section.case-study .feature-content .feature-visual {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 65%;
}
article section.case-study .feature-content .quote {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: stretch;
    background: #db6f72;
    color: #FFF;
    flex-basis: 35%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;
}
article section.case-study .feature-content .quote .words {
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 80%;
}
```

I added `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to `.quote` in order to center it vertically and removed `padding-top` from `.words` to avoid vertical offset.
**Note:** `align-items` aligns vertically if `flex-direction` is row and `justify-content` aligns horizontally. it does the opposite when `flex-direction` is column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox, or you could use a simple transform:

```
article section.case-study .feature-content .quote .words {
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding-top: 4.5em;
    width: 80%;

    // Add these 3 props:
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```